# How to do this integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}+x}ie^{it}dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

For context, I wish to evaluate the below contour integral

$$\int_\Gamma \frac1z dz$$

where $\Gamma$ is a circle of radius $1$ centered at distance $x$ away from origin on positive x-axis. In particular, I want to show that

$$\int_\Gamma \frac1z dz=\int_{\Gamma_0} \frac1z dz=2\pi i$$

when $0\le x < 1$. Here, $\Gamma_0$ is the unit circle. So, I am trying to explicitly evaluate the integral to show that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}+x}ie^{it}dt=\begin{cases}2\pi i & \text{if $0\le x<1$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x\ge 1$} \end{cases}$$

I started with substitution $u=e^{it}+x$ to get $dt=-ie^{-it}du$ which results in

$$\int_{\frac32}^{\frac32}du=1-1=0$$

I am not sure where I did wrong.

Comment: That integral is *not* undefined if $x>1$; it is equal to $0$ then.

Comment: You can continuously deform $\Gamma$ into $\Gamma_0$. Then you can conclude that $\int_{\Gamma_0}\frac{1}{z}dz = 2\pi i$ by Cauchy's Integral Formula. There's no need for parameterization.

Comment: The substitution $u=e^{it}+x$ gives the original contour integral back: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}+x}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{u([0,2\pi])}\frac{1}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$ where $u([0,2\pi])$ is the original circle $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a real-analytic approach, you may invoke the geometric series formula

$$ \frac{1}{1-r} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n $$

which converges uniformly on any compact subset of the unit disk $\mathbb{D} = \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.

**Case 1.** If $|x|<1$, then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it} + x} \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{i}{1 + xe^{-it}} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-xe^{-it})^n \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-int}\, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n \cdot 2\pi \mathbf{1}_{\{n = 0\}} \\
&= 2\pi i.
\end{align*}

**Case 2.** If $|x|>1$, then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it} + x} \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ix^{-1}e^{it}}{1 + x^{-1}e^{it}} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (x^{-1}e^{it})^{n+1} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n+1}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i(n+1)t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Yours is ultimately a contour integral
$$ \int_{\Gamma_0} \frac{dz}{z+x},\qquad \Gamma_0=\{z\in \Bbb C\ :\ |z|=1\}. $$
By the main theorems of complex integration, the value of the integral depends on whether the real parameter $x\geq 0$ is contained within the region bounded by the contour $\Gamma_0$, i.e. the open unit disk $\{|z|<1\}$, or lies outside it. In the latter case, that is, when $x>1$, you may use [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) to deduce that the integral vanishes. In the former case ($x<1$), the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) tells you that the integral evaluates to $$2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=-x} \frac{1}{z+x}=2\pi i.$$

(The integral as written is undefined when $x=1$, although one may certainly calculate its [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).)

---

**Edit.** *(The user has updated their question.)* Alternatively, you may "avoid" the residue theorem as follows. A variant of Cauchy's theorem – a corollary, or a lemma, depending on how you want to go about the proofs – tells you that if two contours $\Gamma_0,\Gamma$ lie within the region of holomorphicity $H$ of the integrand $f(z)$, and they are homotopic (i.e. one is continuously deformable into the other without exiting $H$), then
$$ \int_{\Gamma}f(z)\ d{z} = \int_{\Gamma_0}f(z)\ d{z}.$$
In your case, take $f(z) := 1/z$, $H:=\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, $\Gamma_0 := \{|z|=1\}$, $\Gamma := \{|z+x|=1\}$ to reduce the LHS to a very famous complex integral, which you may compute by substituting $z=e^{it}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated my question to clarify what I want to ask. Sorry for causing some confusion.

Comment: @JohnDavies I do not understand your substitution. You are trying to go from a complex integral in $z$ to a real integral in the angular variable $t$ and back to a complex integral on $u=z+x$ which you seem want to treat as a real integral... To compute the integral explicitly, I reckon you must either go through some hefty trigonometry, or somehow essentially adapt the proof of the residue theorem to this particular case.

Comment: @JohnDavies my last edit may prove to be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

Putting $z=e^{it}$ converts the integral into a contour integral
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{e^{i t}+x} i e^{i t} d t= \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{d z}{z+x}
$$
A.  For $x\ge 1$,
$$z+x=0 \Rightarrow z=-x \textrm{  and hence }|z|=x\ge 1 \textrm{  and there is no singularity inside } |z|=1. $$

$\quad $ By Cauchy’s Theorem,$  \displaystyle  \qquad  \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{d z}{z+x} =0.$

B.  For $x<1$,
$$z+x=0 \Rightarrow z=-x \textrm{  and hence }|z|=x<1 \textrm{  and there is one singularity}-x \textrm{  inside } |z|=1. $$

$\quad $ By Cauchy’s Theorem,$  \displaystyle  \qquad  \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{d z}{z+x} =2\pi i \lim _{z \rightarrow-x}(z+x) \frac{1}{z+x}=2 \pi i.$

We can now conclude that

$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{e^{i t}+x} i e^{i t} d t =\begin{cases}0 & \text { if } x \geqslant 1 \\ 2 \pi i & \text { if } x<1\end{cases}
$$